# problema con Jframe netbeans eventos POO

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, poo

Estoy trabajando con eventos en Java Swing y ocurre que en un JFrame tengo subidas de tres imágenes. Lo que necesito es saber como hago para que al apretar una imagen cuando corra el programa se mueva de forma vertical y yo misma la pueda detener con otro click o bien dándole click a la segunda imagen. Si le doy click a la segunda imagen, la primera se debe detener y se debe empezar a mover la otra.
Como puedo conseguir este resultado en Netbeans?

Comment: Para poder ayudarte vas a tener que dar más informaciones (idealmente en código) sobre las componentes que usas por ejemplo de los imágenes y como quieres posicionarlos. Existen varias formas de hacerlo y sin más información los demás tuvieron que adivinar lo que quieres como resultado final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu envuelves los imágenes en un `JLabel`, puedes agregar un

```
// sea img tu imagen (por ejemplo BufferedImage)
JLabel label = new JLabel(img);

label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     ... procesar el evento ...
  }
});
```

en la parte donde procesas el evento puedes agregar un animador que te mueve los componentes donde los quieres tener.